# http Status Code for NodeJS/ExpressJS Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, express

Error handler:

```
//error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error({error: err});
    //res.status(500);
    res.format({
        'text/html': function() {
            res.render('error', {error: err.message});
        },
        'application/json': function() {
            res.json({'error': err.message});
        }
    });
});
```

Route w/ 404:

```
exports.someRoute = function(req, res, next) {
    ...
    if (!page) {
        return next(new Error('Page not found.')));
    }
    ...
};
```

In error handler, how can I have the appropriate error status code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that information into the error object somehow, either with a simple property like `error.status` or base it on the class hierarchy like `error instanceof NotFound`.

However, a 404 is so common that I'd just add logic to `req` to handle it with something like `req.notFound(message)` or even just use `next('route')` with your last route handling the 404.

Anyway, lots of options.